# Increase count property on object if duplicate value exists in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach, count

I would like to take **list** variable and get it to the point that **updated list** is at but am unsure how.

```
const list = [{name:'apple'},{name:'apple'},{name:'banana'}];

const updatedList = [{name:'apple', count:2},{name:'banana', count: 1}];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will help you ?

```js
const list = [{name:'apple'},{name:'apple'},{name:'banana'}];

const updatedList = Object.values(list.reduce(
  (map, el) => {
    map[el.name] ? map[el.name].count++ : map[el.name] = { ...el,
      count: 1
    };
    return map;
  }, {}
));
console.log(updatedList);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function uptadeLi(list,item,quant) {
    // body...
    for( i in list){
        if (list[i].name === item){
            list[i].count = quant
        }
    }
}
```

With that function you can set each one of the elements of lists , be sure to put the name of item as string

Answer (score 0):

```js
const list = [{name:'apple'},{name:'apple'},{name:'banana'}];
const res = list.reduce((sub,value)=>{
 const index= sub.findIndex(i => i.name===value.name)
    if(index !==-1)
    sub[index].count++
else
    sub.push({name:value.name,count:1})
return sub
},[])
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.reduce()` method to evaluate the count for each item into an object with unique keys:

```
{ "apple": 2, "banana": 1 }
```

Then use `Object.entries()` to convert this into the following array:

```
[ ["apple", 2], ["banana", 1] ]
```

Finally, use `.map()` method to produce:

```
[ {"name": "apple", "count": 2}, {"name": "banana", "count": 1} ]
```

**DEMO**

```js
const list = [{name:'apple'},{name:'apple'},{name:'banana'}];
const updatedList = Object.entries(
    list.reduce(
        (acc,cur) => ({...acc,[cur.name]:(acc[cur.name] || 0) + 1}), 
    {})
)
.map(([name,count]) => ({name,count}));

console.log( updatedList );
```